# Express serve javascipt files if authorised

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

In my client side javascript, I request private content if the user is authorised (using firebase auth) as per below:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (!user) {
    ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
  }
  if (user) {
    import("/private.js").then(module => {
      console.log(module.default);
    });
  }
});
```

All users are served `index.html` from the public firebase hosting URL, but only when a user has been authorised do they request the private content. My `firebase.json` redirects to handle this:

```
 "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
```

I am struggling to set up a firebase functions based express backend to serve the javascript. (I haven't added auth checking yet because I want to get it working simply serving the js first).
My firebase function looks like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/private.js", (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile("private.js", "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(data)
  });

});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

However, when a user gets authorised and the client tries to dynamically import `private.js` I get the following error: `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec`. How do I properly set the MIME type to serve js files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the browser that an error occurred, so that it does not try to parse the response as JavaScript. You can do that by sending a status code starting with 4 (client error) or 5 (server error). Here is an example:

```
app.get("/private.js", (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile("private.js", "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(403).send('Could not load the data.');
    } else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. I need to use:

```
 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript"); //Solution!
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
```

And it works fine.

Comment: Do you want to send a non-private JavaScript file when accesssing `private.js` and there is an error? Otherwise it would be better to just send an error without JavaScript content.

Comment: I will check whether the user is authorised (using firebase admin sdk) and then return js, else return error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
res.type('.js');
res.send(data);
```